# How to resolve SPF configuration to allow Google sending mails?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, gmail, spf

we are configuring DNS for a GMail service, the MX records are configured as to Google says, however, in the DNS check, there is a warning:

```
SPF must allow Google to send mail on behalf of the domain
```

My questions:

- Why is the SPF record for GMail a problem?
- How to resolve that issue?

Many thanks for your help![image: Google Mail error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a SPF DNS record in your DNS server (SPF = Sender Policy Framework). The value of this record is provided in your screenshot already.

It is highly recommended to add not only the SPF record but also a TXT record with the same value. The SPF record will tell receiving Emailservers that the Gmail servers are permitted to send Emails using your domain as sender (details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

If you have a domain provider who is giving you access to his DNS servers, then there might be a special option to set it up easily for you.

Comment: What does "add not only the SPF record but also a TXT record" mean? I have added `@                        IN TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"` and I get the same error.

Comment: Please develop the answer @Ben with what to put in records

Answer (score 1):

I had a record only authorizing emails to be sent from my specific server IP. Here is my final SPF record that works :

```
v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Google SPF documentation helped me : https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031

Comment: wow. that was a very deep grave you dug this question out of :D