# What does this mean: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

In addition to my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/475521/how-to-resolve-spf-configuration-to-allow-google-sending-mails), what does this DNS entry mean:

```
 v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all  ?
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a SPF record.

The `include` directive includes SPF records for the domain **_spf.google.com**. This way Google can add and remove permitted mail servers without you having to change your DNS record whenever Google updates their settings.

The `~all` means that receiving mailservers should accept Emails even the SPF verification failed, but mark them as failed. This is called "SoftFail". In comparison `-all` is a "HardFail", saying "don't accept the Email if the SPF verification failed.

Comment: Can the first use of the word *domain* in this accepted answer be changed to *host* instead? The domain is google.com, the host is _spf.google.com.

Answer (score 3):

> When you are configuring email handling for your domain, you might need to know the IP addresses of the Google Apps mail servers, to help prevent Google messages from being marked as spam. (...)

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

> (...) With this method, your domain automatically inherits changes to the
>   Google IP addresses as they happen.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60764

Comment: Actually, that is to prevent his own messages, sent via google's server but with his own domain, to be classified as spam.